# How to diagnose OpenFileById, 1314 (ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD)

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-sourcesafe

I've written a program that backs up files using VSS.  During the backup I have SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME privileges.

when passing ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, i'm now getting error 1314 (ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD) when calling OpenFileById on Windows8.1 and dont know what to do,  how to diagnose which privilege I do not have

the file is under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps...

tips?

Comment: Can you show your code?  In particular, how are you opening the file?

Comment: Its pretty vanilla stuff,  OpenFileById(etc) - the access permission that is failing the request is ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY

Comment: Well, in particular, are you passing `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`?

Comment: I am, I think I have it figured out - see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what is going on - I was not asking for the SE_SECURITY_NAME which is needed for ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY

on 7 and 8 (not 8.1?) I'm guessing this wasnt required (note that this MSDN page is clear that it's needed) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892(v=vs.85).aspx

anyway, problem solved - thanks for your help Eric